# Return JOIN query result as a JSON

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

I am using a php web service to return SQL queries results to android in a JSON object format. It works fine for me but now I want to be able to return the result of a Joint query in a JSON Object, and I don't know how to do it.
how would be able to put all the result in a JSON object and how do I access the result if I select data from two tables via a INNER JOIN?

**EDIT : HERE IS THE QUERY**
    $query = " `SELECT * FROM question INNER JOIN comment ON question.id = comment.id_question WHERE question.id = :id`";

WHy question is : this does return all I need and I encode it using json_encode. But when I receive it on my Android side, how to I access columns from table question or from table comment knowing that all I have is one json Object, let's said called "json".

Comment: why you dot search in google

Comment: JOIN or just plain select won't make any difference. you get an array of associative array ( column_name => row_value ) in both cases. Have you even tried?

Comment: I googled but I could not find anything. I typed " return joint query results as json". never useful came out.

Comment: That's not the problem. I can encode the result in JSON as send it but how do I access data from table A or table B given that they are all in the same object?

Answer (score 0):

try using json_encode($result) in the PHP side. Then parse it on the other side.

Comment: That's not the problem. I can encode the result in JSON as send it but how do I access data from table A or table B given that they are all in the same object? –

Comment: Check my original post, I added the query

Comment: UP! anybody can help me?

Comment: HELP! please somebody